# Object Visibility in a Multi-threaded Program in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I was going through **Java: Concurrency in Practice**, and in the third chapter, the authors write:

*"...There is no guarantee that operations in one thread will be performed in the order given by the program, as long as the reordering is not detectable from within that thread—even if the reordering is apparent to other threads...."*

I understand that the actual order of execution of statements in one thread might not be what was written in the program (depends upon compiler optimisations and stuff). But for some reason, I cannot decipher the arcane statement written by the authors.

*"...There is no guarantee that operations in one thread will be performed in the order given by the program..."*-Alright. The actual order of execution of statements might differ.

*"...as long as the reordering is not detectable from within that thread—even if the reordering is apparent to other threads..."*-What do they mean by *"....detectable from within the thread...."*?

Comment: As an aside, visibility of "objects" is the wrong idea.  The Java specification is written for fields (class fields and instance fields) not objects.  Thus it is possible to have an object with two fields, one which is perfectly thread safe, and the other field is not thread safe at all.  You can also have multiple fields in a single object that are thread safe and protect by very different schemes.  The is legal and sometimes best practice.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply means that no re-ordering that is performed can invalidate any assertions you could make about the state visible to that thread by looking at the code.

As a simple example:

```
/* 1 */ x = 0;
/* 2 */ boolean c = x == 0;
/* 3 */ x = 1;
```

It's not permitted to move 3 before 2 because that would be detected by the value of `c`.

In other words, a re-ordering that might appear to create a bug when viewed by other threads *is* allowed, but a re-ordering that creates a bug within the thread *is not* allowed.

Comment: I think this explains it, but goddamn I still fear reading what the authors wrote. Thanks a lot @erickson.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having to guess a little bit here, but this is my take on it: you write a program that creates different threads for processing; you create thread A, start it, create thread B, start it, etc.

There is no guarantee that thread A will run before thread B. It is likely, probably even most common, but part of concurrent programming is eliminating this kind of assumption from your thinking. If ANY PART of the logic of B depends on ANY PART of the logic of A executing first, then you need to do programming of your own to guarantee that -- the fact that you have created A before B, nor the fact that you've done anything else outside thread coordination logic, will guarantee that any part of A will execute before any part of B.

As for "detectable within the thread", I assume they mean some kind of semaphore, variable, lock, etc. that allows one thread to know something about the completion of some other thread.

I think it's confusing for them to use "the order given by the program" -- that's really ambiguous, especially to people just starting to try to think about concurrent programming. It does not mean that statements can be reordered regardless of where they are.

Does that help?

Comment: I think it is a good explanation, but I still can't figure out what they mean by "...even if the reordering is apparent to other threads....".

Comment: Again, just guessing -- start A, B, C, D, E -- B hits a condition that causes it to wait on part of A, D hits a condition that causes it to wait on part of B; there is still no guarantee that any part of C will run before any part of D or E. There is a tendency, when doing concurrent code, to still think of things done (and started) earlier as happening before things done (and started) later. It is reinforced by naive testing; the simple cases will tend to work this way. But it may work differently in production, and different at different times, and you must program as though it might.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that they mean that the thread that is "detecting" the ordering is just going to follow the order of execution but not all threads will behave in this manner.